# Sort string with int inside

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list with entry like that:

```
["foo1bar","foo2bar", ..., "foo10bar", "foo11bar", ..., "foo100bar", ...]
```

`foo` is fixed for the set of data (but could vary between the sets), and `bar` can vary even in the same set of data.
If I use `sort`, the list is badly sorted (1, 10, 100, 2, etc.). How can I sort it correctyly? With a regex extractig the numeral part of the strings?

Comment: You should probably use `natsort` as in the accepted answer for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort) if you don't mind using a library.

Comment: I prefer implement it rather than use a third part library.

Comment: In that case, look at some of the further-down answers of the question which use regex.

Comment: list_ = ["foo1bar","foo2bar", "foo10bar", "foo11bar", "foo100bar",]
regex = re.compile('foo(\d+)bar')
try:
    sorted(a, key=lambda x: regex.match(x).group(1))
except IndexError:
    print('Invalid pattern')